# Improving pandas statistics-finding with large csv dataset (~4,000,000 entries)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a Tic-Tac-Toe Bot that analyzes its chances of winning using a CSV files of past games. My problem exists in how slowly the code runs the following: (number of past games that match the current game and are wins)/(number of past games that match the current game). Is there a faster way of generating this percentage within the pandas module, or at all?

The CSV file is formatted: game, outcome and has about 4,000,000 entries, which is likely slowing it down, so I wonder if there is a better approach?

The problem code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Result_data.csv", dtype={"game":"object","outcome":"object"})
def chances(path):
    global data
    return round(data[(data.game.str.startswith(path))&(data.outcome == "W")].shape[0]
                 /data[data.game.str.startswith(path)].shape[0],4) * 100
```

`path` is a string between 1 and 9 characters long and represents the prefix of (presumably multiple) entries in the game column of the data set. Please comment below if you need more information!